# Морфемный разбор

Tags: морфемика, морфология

Пожалуйста, проверьте мой вариант.

1. Слово **кто**. Окончание здесь - **то**, корень - **к**, а основа совпадает с корнем.
2. Слово **самое**. Окончание **ое**. Корень **сам**. Основа совпадает с корнем.
3. Слово **главное** (существительное). Окончание **ое**, корень **глав**, суффикс **н**, а основа - **главн**.

Answer (score 3):

Одна ошибка: у местоимения-существительного *кто* основа (совпадающая с корнем) *кт-*: это слово образует формы именительного и косвенных падежей от разных основ. Всё остальное у вас верно. Кстати, что вы имеете в виду, относя *главный* к существительным?..

Answer (score 0):

Существительное, образованное путем перехода из прилагательного, имеет те же морфемы. Поэтому уточнение части речи в вопросе действительно лишнее.